# css webkit bug: stacked floats with width 0 and hidden overflow

Tags: html, css

This markup shows my problem:
Webkit browsers seem to create an erroneous width on floated parent elements with floated/overflow:hidden elements inside, when their width is set to 0. Is there a known workaround?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>float & width</title>
    <style type="text/css">

        div {
            float: left;
            height: 50px;
        }

        div.section {
            background-color: green;
        }

        div.section div.content {
            background-color: red;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        p {
            clear: both;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<p>width: 0 => Bug</p>
<div class="section">
    <div class="content" style="width: 0;">some content that should not affect the parent div's width.</div>
</div>
<p>width: 1px => good</p>
<div class="section">
    <div class="content" style="width: 1px;">some content that should not affect the parent div's width.</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is really interesting. I tried a lot of variations on the theme with css and got the same results. If there's a width 0 anywhere in the styling for an element, all the styling for that element is ignored. I went looking in the standards and guides and couldn't find anything that says what a browser should do with a zero or negative value of width. One thing it shouldn't do is invalidate everything else, so this is definitely a bug in webkit.

Comment: I had a look at webkit's bugzilla, and several similar looking bugs have been filed. Unfortunately quite some while ago (years) and the current nightly still has this bug. It seems I will have to resort to some dirty trickery :( (and I thought that was an ie exclusive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can get consistent behaviour (at least between webkit and gecko) by giving the outer element some width. Bit of a drag, but doable.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a doctype enabled? Page is in quirks mode as of now.

Comment: Yes, I do. I updated the code. Doctype does not have any effect, unfortunately.